# Why are the Cycles/BI Voronoi Procedural Textures Different?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

The Voronoi procedural texture settings you get when, for example, you create a *Displace* modifier, are much more customizable and there are many more different effects you can achieve them with the Cycles material nodes version of the voronoi procedural.

[image]

### Material nodes:

[image][image]

### Displace modifier:

[image]

Is it possible to get effects like you can with the displace texture with the cycles material nodes texture? For example something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Voronoi Texture used by the displacement modifier is generated differently since it can also be used in the Blender Internal renderer.
The node you speak of is the Cycles texture node, a completely different engine and thus completely different parameters and code.

But yeah, I'd like to see some more procedural textures ported from BI to Cycles, particularly this Voronoi texture and the Cloud texture (which has many different algorithms to choose from, whereas Cycle's Noise texture is a simple Perlin noise if I remember right)

Comment: There is a very simple node setup for getting a "voronoi crackle" texture in the node setups released [here](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/10/16/bwide-nodepack-nodegroups-for-blender-cycles-and-compositor/)

Comment: Probably just uses a color ramp right?

Comment: Nope, just uses two voronoi textures with different scales mixed with *Difference*.

Comment: Not quite the same, but a great shape none the less